# Authorization in microservices architecture

Tags: authentication, jwt, rabbitmq, microservices, token

I'm building an application which will have a microservices architecture, im going to use RabbitMQ as a message broker for service to service communication and also communication from gateway to services. But there's one thing that i wonder about authorization.

With NestJS i can easily send message to any service and get response back from them, but how to handle authentication in each service or more clear question, what is the best practice for sending tokens to services from gateway. Here's summary of what i've done since now.

**My Controller With AuthGuard as you can see**

```
@Controller()
@UseGuards(AuthGuard)
export class UserController {
    constructor(private readonly userService: UserService,
    ) {
    }

    @MessagePattern('user/me')
    async findOne(@Payload() params: FindOneDTO) {
        console.log(params);

        try {

            const user = await this.userService.findOne(params.id);
            return user;
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
            throw err;
        }

    }
}
```

**My Gateway Controller to Send Message to Service**

```
@Controller('account')
@ApiTags("Account Methods")
export class AccountController {


    @Get(':id')
    async me(@Param('id', ParseIntPipe) id: number): Promise<any> {
        const dto: FindOneDTO = {id};
        const userAgentInfo = this.userAgentService.getUserAgentInfo();
        console.log(userAgentInfo);
        return this.sendMicroserviceRequest("user/me", dto);
    }
    
}
```

So let's come to the problem, i want my each service to communicate with auth service by their own, but i don't know what's the best practice to pass authorization tokens to services because right now they only receive DTO's from gateway and no i don't want to add token to dto.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can pass the token as a message header ?

In RabbitMQ, you can put your token in a header in the message properties (https://www.rabbitmq.com/publishers.html#message-properties).

Consumers can then retrieve this token and use it to make calls.

Note : you will have to handle the case of the token expiration.

Comment: decided to handle it in gateway but thanks a lot, might consider that one too.